# Create new database and tables on the fly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was reading the post "Create new database and tables on the fly"
I tried to implement an updated version of the create schema function:

```
public static function createSchema($schemaName)
{
    $dbName = "db_{$schemaName}";

    return DB::getSchemaBuilder()
        ->getConnection()
        ->statement("CREATE DATABASE :schema", ['schema' => $dbName ]);
}
```

but I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 (SQL: CREATE DATABASE :schema)

PDO does not allowed to bind params on a create database query. So i'm not sure how to create DB's on the fly as safely as possible. Can anyone show me the way, before i have to introduce a security flaw in our site.

Comment: why there is no use of $schemaName variable in function and insted of you use $dbName in database name.

Comment: @jigsVirani look on the third line

Comment: *"PDO does not allowed to bind params on a create database query."* - Correct. Use a pre-defined variable/safelist.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but how to create a new user and grant all access to this database on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use bindings with `CREATE DATABASE` and PDO, because in `CREATE DATABASE foo`, foo isn't a quoted identifier, it's a raw new database name. You'll need to do any sanity checking yourself rather than relying on parameter binding to protect you.

```
public static function createSchema($schemaName)
{
    $dbName = "db_{$schemaName}";

    $quotedDbName = preg_replace("/[^_a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $dbName);
    return DB::statement("CREATE DATABASE $quotedDbName");
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590594/create-database-with-pdo-in-php) for more details about `CREATE DATABASE` with PDO binding.

Comment: it was a long a rough journey, but we did it. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: *"I removed the "safelist" from your edit as it had no explanation -- I would love to know more about that, but Googling didn't help"* - Commenting/replying here instead of the other answer should it get deleted. http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17494293/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17494356/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/31815204/ as a few examples.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean -- a whitelist of acceptable values. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static function createSchema($schemaName)
{
    // We will use the `statement` method from the connection class so that
    // we have access to parameter binding.
    return DB::getConnection()->statement('CREATE DATABASE :schema', ['schema' => 'db_' . $schemaName]);
}
```

i believe you dont need schema builder here

Comment: Correct -- you also don't need `->getConnection()`

Comment: hmm... so which pdo driver to use?

Comment: still can't bind that. Same applies to tables/columns.

Comment: this is some kind of safelist $quotedDbName = preg_replace("/[^_a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $dbName); in Ben's  answer